# @Transactional causing @Inject fields to change

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm running into a very strange problem with a jUnit test and bean proxies.  As part of my test, I am manually adding beans to the application context, and forcing a bean re-wire using `AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowire()` to force an autowire update.

If I place a breakpoint in the jUnit test and inspect the bean I am autowire updating, I can see my my field has been properly updated and includes the new beans I programatically added to the context.

However, when the execution moves to the actual bean and I place a breakpoint in the method I am testing, the beans I added to the context do not appear.

My Bean-under-test method is annotated with `@Transactional`.  If I remove the `@Transactional` annotation, the autowire field is properly updated.

I have tried adding @Transaction to my jUnit test method, but it has had no impact.

Junit (implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor):

```
@Test
@Rollback
@Transactional
public void testExecuteSinglePatch() throws Exception {
    GenericBeanDefinition definition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    definition.setBeanClass(Patch1.class);
    definition.setAutowireMode(GenericBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE);
    definition.setLazyInit(false);
    registry.registerBeanDefinition("PATCH_1", definition);

    applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Patch.class);
    // reinit the patchEngine
    autowireBeanFactory.autowireBean(patchEngine);
    patchEngine.execute();

    assertEquals(1, patchRepository.findByName( new Patch1().getName()).size() );
}
```

Bean Under Test (PatchEngine):

```
@Inject private Map<String, Patch> availablePatches;

@Transactional
public void execute() throws Exception{

    // loop over all the pending patches, and apply them.  Keep looping over while patches exist and at least one patch is applied per iteration
    boolean appliedPatch = true;
    while( !availablePatches.isEmpty() && appliedPatch ){
        // no applied patches this iteration yet
        appliedPatch = false;

        // do some logic here
    }
}
```

When I set my debug context to the jUnit test and examine `patchEngine`, the bean id for `patchEngine.availablePatches` is different than the bean id found when I set my debug context to the patchEngine.execute method.

However, if I remove the `@transactional` annotation from the `execute()` method, then the ids are the same.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening?  Why is `@Transactional` impacting the dependency injection?  How does the @Transactional impact the proxy and how to ensure that proxy is properly populated?  Does the annotation cause a different context to be used?  Is there a way to solve this problem?

I'm using Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE and jUnit 4.11.  Could this be a Spring bug?

Comment: Is there a simple but complete example you can give so we can try to reproduce this behavior? Classes and context, all.

Comment: I'll if I can put together a small demo project.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In trying to prepare a simple but complete exercise, I had trouble reproducing the error.  So I started adding all my extra classes back in, until I noticed that I had accidentally duplicated an applicationContext for the transaction manager/entity manager/etc in a JavaConfig and had both active at the same time.  So it appears that things were somehow being double proxied (not entirely sure how that was happening).  I removed the JavaConfig configuration class and everything is working as expected.

Comment: Should I just delete this question since it is not longer relevant and due to user-error?

Comment: Sure, unless the answer might help someone out. But without the clarifications I asked for the other day, it might be hard to piece together the conditions in which your problem occurred.